# How to change integer value in C#?

Tags: c#, integer

I had made an integer named lifePoints then I set an If statement to CHANGE the integer's value from 100 to 90 how

```cs
int lifePoints = 100;
// not a full code but just giving an explanation
if (player == ("attackthem!"))
  {

    change integer value here. how?

  }
```

I searched google and it came out changing String to integer.

Comment: `lifePoints -= 10;` or `lifePoints = lifePoints - 10;`

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to C#

Comment: No offence, but why ask the question here? This is such a basic question, you would benefit from running through some C# tutorials far more than us answering this for you.

Comment: That's true. This is not an issue with you being new to C#, but rather with you being new to programming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please show us what you have tried yourself, and tell us how that worked or din't work.

Comment: @BrokeWebDeveloper welcome to programming! Ignore them and just go on. Just do googling first next time so you can avoid these guys :)

Comment: well I searched google and the results are different

Comment: And did you try any of those Google results?

Comment: No. because they are different than what I searched.

Comment: What did you search for then?

Comment: how to change integer value in C#

Comment: What you want to do is to *subtract* `10` from `lifePoints`, right? Even without knowledge of programming it should have been easy to guess and try something like `lifePoints - 10`. Now comes the question about how to store the result back into `lifePoints`, which should have been very obvious after reading just about any decent book, as *assignment* using `=` should have been introduced rather early.

Comment: I don't use any tutorial, I'm 10 yrs old...

Comment: Well kudos on trying to learn, like I said you should find a tutorial online, you will learn a lot more doing that. Also, you really need to be 13 to use Stack Overflow!

Comment: Ok.. I just started C# (even though I already learned HTML, CSS, learning JavaScript and Java (Pretty advanced in Java though..))

Comment: C# is very similar to Java, so you could easily have guessed the answer to this question :)

Comment: I never thought that....  better use tutorials then!...

Comment: Oh well then good for you! I started programming myself around that age. But please, I really recommend that you try to get some beginners book, or go through a beginners tutorial. Learning a language (spoken or programming) by guessing isn't really good. And you can't really come here for every such small problem you have. I'm sorry if that's not what you want to hear, but some kind of books or tutorials or you won't have a chance to learn properly. And if you know Java or JavaScript, then some of that knowledge carries over and can be used for C#. Like assignment... ;)

Comment: System.out.println("I learned my lesson");

Comment: @BrokeWebDeveloper This may help you: [How do I improve my knowledge in C#](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm)

Answer (score 2):

```
{
   lifePoints -= 10;
}
```

which corresponds to

```
{
   lifePoints = lifePoints - 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *set* it to `90`, then:

```
lifePoints = 90;
```

If you want to *substract* `10`, then:

`lifePoints -= 10;` OR: `lifePoints = lifePoints - 10;`

Answer (score 0):

```
int lifePoints = 100;
// not a full code but just giving an explanation
if (player == ("attackthem!"))
  {

    lifePoints = 90; //CHANGE the integer's value from 100 to 90

  }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.